# typedef redefinition error Xcode 5, iOS7 and 64bit vs 32bit

Tags: ios, c, xcode

I am trying to build an existing project of 32 bit in 64bit ios 7 using xcode 5. During build time with architecture arm64 , typedef redefinition error occurs . Xcode 5 llvm compiler shows the redine error. In below I post the sample code where I got error mainly.

```
#if defined (__LP64__)

typedef long int64_t;

typedef unsigned long u_int64_t;
#else

typedef long long          int64_t;
 //shows redefine error int64_t long vs long long

typedef unsigned long long u_int64_t; 
//shows redefine error u_int64_t unsigned long vs unsigned long long 
#endif
```

Comment: Where is that code from? Is it yours? If so, why are you trying to define existing type names like `int64_t`?

Comment: its existing project code which was successfully built in 32bit mode using Xcode 4.6 . Now I want to build it in 64 bit with arm64 architecture.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply remove these definitions from your code.
Both `int64_t` and `u_int64_t` are already defined in the iOS SDK headers.
(If necessary, add `#include <stdint.h>`, which is the standard header for
exact-width integer types.)

The the error actually occurs in the
first part of your code when compiling for 64-bit, because your definitions

```
typedef long int64_t;
typedef unsigned long u_int64_t;
```

conflict with the iOS SDK definitions

```
typedef long long       int64_t;
typedef unsigned long long  u_int64_t;
```

since `long` and `long long` are different types (but of the ***same size*** on 64-bit ARM).